# I accidentally removed my user from multiple groups, how do I find out what they were?

Tags: users, group

When trying to add my user to a new group to run an application (Kismet), I accidentally made it the ONLY group my user is in. I had run the `groups` command and saw seven or so other groups I was in, but when I logged out and logged back in to save my changes those other groups are gone.

I have root access, but my bash history doesn't show output.

**How do I find out what groups I was in?** I know how to add myself back to them, just not how to figure out what they were.

Comment: Backup copies of /etc/group? Find files you own that have gids not equal to kismet?

Comment: The files thing is a clever idea, I ended up listing default groups and restoring those. Hoping I don't run into crazy access issues in the future now...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had searched around previously, but just found this answer which basically solves my needs: [Default groups for user in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/a/219353/547142)

1. Login as root (because I was removed from sudoers group):

   `su - root`
2. List the setup log from creating my user

   `grep user-setup /var/log/installer/syslog`
3. Then I ran the command (using the list of groups from the above command)

   `usermod -a -G adm,cdrom,lpadmin,sudo,sambashare,dip username`
4. Log out and back in, done!

Answer (score 3):

If you're still logged in anywhere, you can run the command `groups` to list the groups that the running process is in. If you're logged in on a terminal that you don't have access to, or more generally if you have a program running somewhere from before the group change, you can list that process's groups with `ps -o rgroup,supgrp 1234` where `1234` is the process ID (that's for Linux, the syntax may be different on other Unix variants).

Whenever you change something about your account, it's a good idea to remain logged in and try logging in in another terminal to validate the change!

If you used `vigr` or some sufficiently compatible tool, it leaves a backup in `/etc/group-`. This does not apply to all tools, for example the `addgroup` command on Debian doesn't make a backup. Make a copy of the backup before editing the file again, otherwise it'll be overwritten.

It's a good idea to make frequent backups of `/etc`. I recommend using [etckeeper](http://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/) (available on most Linux distributions) to keep a full history under version control (etckeeper automatically before and after installing packages, but you should commit all changes manually anyway with a meaningful log message).

Comment: "Whenever you change something about your account, it's a good idea to remain logged in and try logging in in another terminal to validate the change!" << Great advice, this would've prevented the issue. I also didn't know where to backup the list.